# Form collection, going into getXXX instead of setXXX or addXXX

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.1 and I just being mad at **form collections that are not saving correctly**,

Here's a simple example of what appears to me as the weirdest thing : https://gist.github.com/2829001

Why when i'm saving the form (working on a `Car` object), it adds a `condition` via the `getConditions` instead of `setConditions` / `addCondition`

**It results in the car reference not being saved in the Condition Table.**

I'm just being sceptical at the need of adding a `prePersist` and `preUpdate` to loop conditions object to set the Car reference.

If we need the prePersist / preUpdate hook, then what's the goal of addXXX / setXXX ? Maybe I am missing something (i really hope so).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the option `by_reference` on the collection field to `false`. Also, make sure to use the latest version of Doctrine, since a bug in `PersistentCollection` was recently fixed that affects collection fields.